# Converting site from .html to .php

Tags: php, html, redirect

my site has now become sufficiently large for me to think it's necessary to convert the pages to php pages to help me update it in the future. The problem is: my site has a number of links to it on various websites across the web. Eg these links point to www.example.com/page1.html but the page is now going to be renamed www.example.com/page1.php

How would people get around this problem? Simply redirect the html page to the php page? Are there any alternatives? Does this have any implications for SEO?

Thanks

Comment: If your website contains static pages, there's no need to replace `.html` by `.php`. In fact, if it's really necessary, you can also parse  `.html` files as PHP

Comment: @Rob W: He said he needs this to help him update it in the future (maintainability), which is a valid reason.

Comment: Basically I'm just including the navigation bar, footer, header etc as php includes. I was under the impression if you have any php includes in your page it must have a .php extension as opposed to .html. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Personally, I would never choose to manually maintain static pages. There is always the option of using a caching system that compiles your dynamic pages into static pages to improve speed. There are some CMS's based on this concept. But for most use cases, regular caching (file, db, or in memory) is just fine.

Comment: Could you explain what caching is? Or point me somewhere that explains it? My search on google only seems to tell me about temporary internet files...

Comment: Caching is storing data in a faster storage (or same storage but already processed). Eg: you have a complex query that takes many seconds of execution, and many MB of RAM. Then you cache it into a file, that you refresh only once per hour (the file is considered temporary then, because it's only useful for some time, and nothing is lost if it gets deleted). The same can be done with full web pages.

Comment: "php extension as opposed to .html" What they are saying is you can alter your .htaccess files to execute html files. Once you do, as long as the html file contains nothing but php, you can include them as well. 
edit: If you do include html in the file it will be dumped at the point of the include which may be a technique you want to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

URL Rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

More directly to the point: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html

Answer (score 4):

The least intrusive method is to simply have your webserver treat .html files as PHP files. That way your links can stay intact, and progressively replacing static .html pages with actual php-enabled pages can be done in an essentially transparent method to users.

Remember, there is no such thing as a "PHP script". There are only files that contain `<?php ... ?>` code blocks, which will get interpreted/executed when the containing file is passed through PHP.

Unless some of your html pages contain SAMPLES of php code that could be misinterpreted as actual code, then there shouldn't be any issues with making run through PHP.

As a minor side benefit, it wouldn't be immediately obvious that your site is running on PHP, as all the urls would say ".html". But then, that's security by obscurity and shouldn't be counted on to be anything in the way of real security.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a 301 redirect (this works fine for SEO), or just rewrite the URLs so page1.html points to page1.php internally.

Both solutions can be done with the [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) file (assuming you are using apache as your webserver)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using a tool such as Dreamweaver to manage your website. That way you can easily rename pages and update the links with a few clicks.

:)

Comment: This doesn't account for any implications of 404'ed pages, SEO, etc.

Comment: Does make it easier to manage mind, What about a redirect on the html page in Java or simular?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Marc B,

there is no such thing as a "PHP script". There are only files that contain  code blocks, which will get interpreted/executed when the containing file is passed through PHP.

i would say that it's true and if you want to absolutely turn your html files into php files simply put `<?php` before your `<DOCTYPE html!>` line and then `?>` after your `</html>` line save it and rename it as *example.php* if it is *example.html*

if you are windows8 or higher user then click on 'View' in file explorer and then check 'File name Extension'. Now you'll be able to see the extension example.html and many other files extensions like .jpg, .mp3 e.t.c...., This helps you to easily rename exactly like example.php but not example.php.html as .html will not be visible if you are not checked File name Extension.

Answer (score -1):

I  would suggest that you use [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) (kickass php framework).

You can maintain the existing site structure also, by making use of CodeIgniter's `URL suffix` option .

Comment: He would still have to use .htaccess, unless he wants to manually write each URL. Anyway, CI is outdated, poorly architected, and teaches bad practices.

Comment: ofc he has to use url rewriting ( to remove index.php from url's of CI ) , but using codeigniter will definitively help him to speedup things . btw, which is the most updated framework according to you ?

Comment: CI is based on the singleton anti-pattern, half procedural half OOP, and has been built for php 4 originally. Please let it die already.

Comment: Have to agree with @HappyDeveloper, built our stuff on top of CI and ended up rewriting most of it for security reasons, and the rest of it because it didn't do anything we needed it to.